# Where am I going wrong with \P{Cn}?

Tags: .net, regex

I was trying to match a string that has only valid characters, and I came across \P{Cn} which I understand for matching an assigned character.

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/0000-0FFF

Here I see 0x0870-0x89F is an unassigned "region" (not sure what to call it).

When I test a match should fail against a single/multiple of these characters it does indeed fail `"\u0880"`, however if it contains an assigned character `"\u0880 letters"` then it does not fail to match.

What might I be misunderstanding about this situation? I would be grateful to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use anchors with a quantifier:

```
^\P{Cn}*$
```

or - if you do not want to match an empty string:

```
^\P{Cn}+$
```

It matches:

- `^` - start of a string
- `\P{Cn}*` - any 0+ chars other than in the `Cn` category
- `$` - end of string (or `\z` to match the very end).

Comment: this fixed my problem, thank you very much! however, i'm still unsure about why the anchors made the difference. i mean, why \P{Cn}* is not enough to assert a match _fail_ without the anchors, given a string with an unassigned character anywhere within?

Comment: @ｌｉｌａｈ The `Regex.IsMatch` method does not ensure the whole string is matched (unlike `String#matches` in Java, or `re.fullmatch()` in Python 3). You must tell the regex engine to explicitly anchor the match at both ends of the string.